# Replace part of string between special characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I have following string: "/language/account/home" and
I need to change first word "language" for example to another word using jquery. 
Word "language" can change. How can I do this. Using some reg expression for replacing only first word between two slashes or there are some jquery functions?

```
var url = "/language/account/home";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regular expressions here:

```
var url = "/language/account/home";
var arr = url.split('/');
arr[1] = "replacement";
var repl = arr.join('/');
//=> "/replacement/account/home"
```

Comment: i used array but i thought there is a better solution

Comment: Any problem on using array?

Comment: There are solutions avoiding array but since IMO this was pretty straight forward to split and act on whatever parts of array you want to act.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple replacement or use split as in anubhava answer.

```
var result = url.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/, '/whatyouwant');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.+?(?=\/)
```

Try this .

Replace by

`\yourword`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/10

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
url = "/new" + url.substr(1 + url.substr(1).indexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
var str = "/language/account/home";
var res = str.replace(/^\/[^/]+/, "/newword");
console.log(res);
```